# "Good luck at...." or "Good luck with..."?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct and why?

1. "Good luck at your new job" or
2. "Good luck with your new job"?

Comment: How are you judging "correct"?

Comment: Good luck in your new question.